# Add alt attribute to image if doesn't exists

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set atribute to all images. Now I have something like this:

```
function init(){
    imgs = document.images;
   for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
      imgs[i].alt="test";
   }
}
```

but now I am replace all alts. How to add an attribute only to images that don't have it?

Comment: What have you tried...? Why not just test the value of `alt` before applying the new value? You should also avoid accessing and setting *attribute* values as properties, as the behavior is not consistent across browsers - see [What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace the alt attributes of all images with no alt atttribute or the alt attribute set to an empty string:

```
function init(){
   imgs = document.images;
   for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
      if (!imgs[i].alt){
        imgs[i].alt="test";
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the images have an attribute using the `getAttribute()` method:

```js
init();

function init(){
    imgs = document.images;
   for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
   
      console.log(imgs[i].getAttribute("alt"));
   
     // Here check
      if (imgs[i].getAttribute("alt") === null) {
        imgs[i].alt="test";
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<img alt="hello">
<img alt="hello">
<img>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by checking if given element has `alt` attribute.

```
function init()
{ 
   imgs = document.images;
   for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) { 
        if (imgs[i].hasAttribute("alt")) {
            continue;
        }
        imgs[i].alt="test"; 
    } 
}
```